# How to resume IntelliSense if I quit it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, intellisense

For example:
Suppose there are three objects, `Model`, `ModelParam`, `ModelParamValue`
And I have such a line:

```
f(Model)
```

I would like IntelliSense to show the `ModelParam` and `ModelParamValue` options as I type "p" like this

```
f(Modelp)
```

How should I change Visual Studio's setting to accomplish this?
Also, If I type `Model`, there'll be the three options in the IntelliSense window, but if I hit ESC, the window would be gone and even if I type "p", the window won't come back. How should I fix this?

The reason I'm asking this is that this feature is available in SQL Server 2008, so I guess it only needs some configuration to work properly in VS.

I'm writing program using C# in VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

By pressing the keycombination to bring up intellisense:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

When you have for example the following snippet:

```
void testTest() {}
void testTast() {}

int main() {
    testT //press ctrl + space after this and it will bring up the 2 possibilities
    testTa //press ctrl + space after this and it will fill in testTast
    testt //press ctrl + space after this and it will bring up the 2 possibilities
}
```

Works in both Visual studio 2010 and Visual studio 2012, and very likely in other versions aswell.

Comment: Oh actually I saw this shortcut somewhere before, but the problem is that it conflicts with the "Change Input Method" shortcut...I'll see if this works after I disable that IME shortcut.